# Write dword value in Registry with Delphi

Tags: delphi, registry, dword

My program has a TWebBrowser where the user can open all kinds of local documents. To avoid that for example a Word document is opened in Word instead of in the TWebBrowser (that is to say, in Internet Explorer), I successfully use a fix in the Registry, by executing a .reg file with this instruction:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.12]
>   "BrowserFlags"=dword:80000024

I am trying to introduce that instruction in the Delphi program itself, with this code:

```
procedure RegOpenExplorer;
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg:= TRegistry.Create;
  try
    reg.RootKey:=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    reg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.12\', true);
    reg.WriteInteger('BrowserFlags',80000024);
    reg.CloseKey;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It does not work, actually the effect is undoing the fix.

When successfully manipulated with the .reg file (or manually), the Registry key looks like this:

[image: good key]

But with my unsuccessful Delphi Code, the key becomes as follows:

[image: bad key]

The difference is the number in brackets, but that is something that the Registry introduces automatically by itself.

Comment: This is probably a hex representation. In Delphi you must write $80000024 then.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe: Thanks! It works like this!

Comment: That change affects way more that your program. You should solve the problem properly.

Comment: That's a global change, not just for your app. Your uninstaller is going to get as much use as your app. You'll be lucky if you're not blacklisted everywhere, including most malware and AV software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numeric value in the `.reg` file is encoded as hex.  Since you are passing an integer literal to `WriteInteger()`, you need to prefix it with a `$` to make the compiler interpret it as hex:

```
reg.WriteInteger('BrowserFlags', $80000024);
```

That being said, note that you are writing to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, and more importantly you are opening the key with `KEY_ALL_ACCESS` access rights (the default access rights that `TRegistry` uses).  This is going to require you to run your app elevated as an administrator, if it is not already.  You should be setting the `TRegistry.Access` property to `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead, and maybe even writing to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead.

```
procedure RegOpenExplorer;
var
  reg: TRegistry;
begin
  reg := TRegistry.Create(KEY_SET_VALUE);
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE; // or HKEY_CURRENT_USER
    if reg.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\Classes\Word.Document.12\', true) then
    try
      reg.WriteInteger('BrowserFlags', $80000024);
    finally
      reg.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    reg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Excellent, that also solves the "Failed to set protected data" error that I was sometimes getting.